# Trouble installing Dirt-Samples quark in SuperCollider for Tidal

Tags: supercollider

I am trying to install [Tidal](http://tidalcycles.org/getting_started.html), and I am running in to trouble installing the Dirt-Samples quark in SuperCollider 3.6.6.  I followed the directions in the [SuperDirt](https://github.com/musikinformatik/SuperDirt) repository and put the SuperDirt, Dirt-Samples, and Vowel quarks in ~/.local/share/SuperCollidor/Extensions/quarks/.  I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell Inspiron 3521.

In SuperCollider I am running Quarks.gui.  In the list of quarks, Vowel appears to be installed, with a + next to it, but Dirt-Samples and SuperDirt have a - next to them.  When I select Dirt-Samples so there is a * next to it and click Apply, I get this error in the SuperCollidor IDE:

```
ARGS:
   Character 47 '/'

PROTECTED CALL STACK:
    Meta_MethodError:new    0x3c794c0
            arg this = DoesNotUnderstandError
            arg what = nil
            arg receiver = nil
    Meta_DoesNotUnderstandError:new 0x3c7b480
            arg this = DoesNotUnderstandError
            arg receiver = nil
            arg selector = split
            arg args = [ / ]
    Object:doesNotUnderstand        0x2adebc0
            arg this = nil
            arg selector = split
            arg args = nil
    a FunctionDef   0x2fa4900
            sourceCode = "<an open Function>"
            arg oneq = Quark: Dirt-Samples
    ArrayedCollection:do    0x3b8fe80
            arg this = [ Quark: Dirt-Samples ]
            arg function = a Function
            var i = 0
    QuarkSVNRepository:checkout     0x2fa43c0
            arg this = a QuarkSVNRepository
            arg q = Quark: Dirt-Samples
            arg localRoot = /home/nathan/.local/share/SuperCollider/quarks
            arg sync = true
            var subfolders = nil
            var fullCheckout = [  ]
            var pathSoFar = nil
            var skeletonCheckout = [  ]
            var args = nil
    Quarks:checkout 0x3907d00
            arg this = a Quarks
            arg name = Dirt-Samples
            arg version = nil
            arg sync = true
            var q = Quark: Dirt-Samples
    Quarks:install  0x3909ac0
            arg this = a Quarks
            arg name = Dirt-Samples
            arg includeDependencies = true
            arg checkoutIfNeeded = true
            var q = nil
            var deps = nil
            var installed = nil
            var dirname = nil
            var quarksForDep = nil
    a FunctionDef   0x39da400
            sourceCode = "<an open Function>"
            arg qView = a QuarkViewQt
    ArrayedCollection:do    0x3b8fe80
            arg this = [ a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, a QuarkViewQt, ...etc...
            arg function = a Function
            var i = 92
    Function:prTry  0x2dc7300
            arg this = a Function
            var result = nil
            var thread = a Thread
            var next = a Function
            var wasInProtectedFunc = true
    Function:protect        0x2dc6880
            arg this = a Function
            arg handler = a Function
            var result = nil
    a FunctionDef   0x2d870c0
            sourceCode = "<an open Function>"
    Function:prTry  0x2dc7300
            arg this = a Function
            var result = nil
            var thread = a Thread
            var next = nil
            var wasInProtectedFunc = false

CALL STACK:
    DoesNotUnderstandError:reportError   0x4d51268
            arg this = <instance of DoesNotUnderstandError>
    < closed FunctionDef >   0x4d48418
            arg error = <instance of DoesNotUnderstandError>
    Integer:forBy   0x468a6d8
            arg this = 0
            arg endval = 0
            arg stepval = 2
            arg function = <instance of Function>
            var i = 0
            var j = 0
    SequenceableCollection:pairsDo   0x49be958
            arg this = [*2]
            arg function = <instance of Function>
    Scheduler:seconds_   0x2a7cbd8
            arg this = <instance of Scheduler>
            arg newSeconds = 1470285930.1456
    Meta_AppClock:tick   0x3ec45a8
            arg this = <instance of Meta_AppClock>
            var saveClock = <instance of Meta_SystemClock>
    Process:tick   0x465a508
            arg this = <instance of Main>
^^ The preceding error dump is for ERROR: Message 'split' not understood.
RECEIVER: nil
```

I don't know what is causing this 'split' error.  Any help getting from here to being able to run SuperDirt.start in SuperCollider would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These quarks (SuperDirt, Dirt-Samples, Vocal) all appear to install correctly in SuperCollider v3.7+. There were major fixes and improvements to Quarks between 3.6.x and 3.7, so this will probably be solved by upgrading.

If you're dependent on 3.6.x specifically, you can probably proceed in using Tidal. Placing the files in the quarks folder as you described is ALL that's required to install them (the Quarks GUI does exactly and only this) - there's nothing additional done by the Quarks gui / Quarks.install(). A simple recompile / restart should pick up the quarks and everything should work fine.

https://supercollider.github.io/download

Comment: I am only using version 3.6.6 because that is what is in the apt repository.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'recompile / restart'?  How would I go about recompiling supercollider? @scztt

Comment: I closed SuperCollider, restarted it, and tried running SuperDirt.start.  It gave no errors and appears to be working!  Thanks!